# No Typescript definitions or docs for Material UI v5 TextField

Tags: typescript, material-ui

[Here is the corresponding playground.](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-albattani-d23ovm?file=/src/App.tsx)

TypeScript typings on `TextField` don't work at all. Why?

```js
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* hover 'multiline': does NOT show docs/types ==> bad */}
      <TextField multiline={true} />
      {/* hover 'multiline': does show docs/types ==> good */}
      <Select multiline={true} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I introduced a Select as well which highlights the expected behavior and I don't understand why everything works fine with Select (or other components), but not the TextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `Material-UI` does not have a the type definition for `TextField` defined in the same way as `Select` which affects IDEs trying to provide a description on-hover.

You just need to provide a type-definition manually for `TextField`. Using the same strategy as the `Select` type-definition, except using the `InputProps`

Try the following which I verified in a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-autocomplete-textfield-forked-o5fwom):

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/local-types"],
    "paths": {
      "@mui/material/TextField": ["./src/local-types/mui__material__TextField"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/local-types/**"]
}
```

**src/local-types/mui__material__TextField** (two double-underscores)

```
import { InputProps } from "@mui/material";

declare const TextField: ((props: InputProps) => JSX.Element) & {
  muiName: string;
};
```

[image]

```
export default TextField;
```

Comment: [Have you tried what you wrote or is this just a wild guess?](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-cherry-z29vlp?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: My apologies, I read your question too quickly and didn't fully understand. My suggestion to use @mui/types and a `tsconfig.json` was incomplete and not tested --- I revised the answer now with a work-around for what appears to be a problem with the MUI library? May be worth-mentioning to the repository maintainers.

Comment: [Filed an issue here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36232)
Accepting now, because answer is now valuable. Thanks